# How to perform an action after multiple subscriptions are completed/teardown

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm creating an ionic refresher. I have a component which performs multiple get requests. Each of them is in its own method. What i'm trying to implement is, I want to execute `event.target.complete()` after all subscriptions are done. Below is what I tried to do:

```
private _dataFromOne;
private _dataFromTwo;

ngOnInIt() {
    this.getAllData();
}

/*This method will be called from HTML as well with $event*/
private getAllData(event = null) {
    if ($event) {
          // So if it was only one method, then this would work
        this.methodOne().add(() => {
            event.target.complete()  // teardown logic. End when _subOne is unsubscribed
        });
        // This is where I'm confused. How do I do it when subscription from both method is unsubscribed?
        // this.methodTwo();
    } else {
        this.methodOne();
        this.methodTwo();
    }
}

private methodOne() {
    return this.doGetRequest.get().subscribe((data) => {
        this._dataFromOne = data;
    });
}

private methodTwo() {
    return this.doSomeGetRequest.get().subscribe((data) => {
        this._dataFromTwo = data;
    });
}
```

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't subscribe directly in methods `methodOne()` and `methodTwo()`. You can share the returned Observable for example.

Comment: I'm not subscribing to it. I'm just adding a [teardown](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subscription#add-) to be called after subscription is unsubscribed.

Comment: Where are you getting the .add method on your methodOne function from?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter I'm returning Subscription (not Observable) from method. That contains .add() method. see: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subscription#subscription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try returning `Observable` from the 2 methods and merge them into one:

```
private getAllData(event = null) {
    merge(
        this.methodOne(),
        this.methodTwo()
    ).pipe(
        finalize(() => {
            if (event) {
                event.target.complete();
            }
        }),
    ).subscribe();
}


private methodOne() {
    return this.doGetRequest.get().pipe(tap(data => {
        this._dataFromOne = data;
    }));
}

private methodTwo() {
    return this.doSomeGetRequest.get().pipe(tap(data => {
        this._dataFromTwo = data;
    }));
}
```

or without `tap` (side effects outside subscribe):

```
private getAllData(event = null) {
    forkJoin(
        this.methodOne(),
        this.methodTwo()
    ).subscribe(([data1, data2]) => {
        this._dataFromOne = data1;
        this._dataFromTwo = data2;
    }, err => {
        //what do you do if one of them fails?
    }, () => {
        if (event) {
            event.target.complete();
        }
    });
}


private methodOne() {
    return this.doGetRequest.get1();
}

private methodTwo() {
    return this.doSomeGetRequest.get2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate the Observable within a function that resolves a Promise after your results have been fetched, stack all those Promises into a Promise Array and use the [Promise.All()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)